# Why isn't my display:inline working?

Tags: html, css, inline

I am trying to make a menu with submenus. I wrote my HTML and it looks like:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">dropdown 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">dropdown 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">submenu </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">submenu 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">submenu 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">submenu 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I have a stylesheet linked to it, and it looks like:

```
nav ul {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
}
nav ul ul {
    display:none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

For some reason the list is displayed as a block. I tried `float:left`, and it made no difference.

Comment: which list is displayed as block?

Comment: Did you rightclick, 'Inspect Element' on the offending object, and actually look which styles are applied in which order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to to put `display:inline-block` for li elements:

```
nav li {
display:inline-block;
}
```

check here the example: http://jsfiddle.net/9y1uzqye/1/

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks. Sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the individual list items use block display, not the list itself.